# How to create a button to duplicate a table below in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Goal:** I want to create a button that replicates a set of rows and columns and paste below the current set.

**Problem:** I've created a table on google sheets that I would need to replicate over and again with different values.
I know that If I wanted to do that, I could simply copy paste the rows and paste it below to recreate it and change the values accordingly but I was hoping to automate that process in the form of a button but i'm not sure if that it's possible.

**From suggestions below I've come up with the following:**

```
function duplicateTable(){
  
//data source
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"); //get sheet by name

  
//Specifies the sheet you want the table to be inserted to- same sheet here
  let targetSheet =  sheet; 


//Select range that you want to copy from sheet
let sourceRange = sheet.getRange("A10:O14");
let rangeDestination = targetSheet.getRange("A15:O19");

sourceRange.copyTo(rangeDestination); }
```

My only question now is how do I make the ranges dynamic?
because they wont be the same everytime
Example:

[image]

When you click the button it should essentially recreate the same table below the existing one
Is this possible in google sheets?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

#### Script:

```
function dupTable(){
  
//data source
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start'); //name of your sheet

  let sheetRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  
//Specifies the sheet you want the table to be inserted to- same sheet here
  let targetSheet =  sheet; 

//Here we specify the range where we want the table inserted Row= 13 , Column 1. If you want it somewhere else you can adjust the numbers
  sheetRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(13,1)); 

}
```

#### Button:

You add a button via the *Insert > Drawing menu* in Google Sheets. This brings up the drawing editor where you can easily add a box and style it to look like a button. Once you click *'Save and Close'*, this drawing gets added to your Google Sheet. You can click on it to resize it or drag it around to reposition it.

#### Assign the script to the button:

Click the three little dots in the top right of the drawing and select Assign Script as seen here:

[image]
[image]

Where dupTable is the name of the method in our script. After you click *'OK'* you are ready to create as many tables as needed using the button.

Comment: this is actually really helpful to help me get started although I dont think its quite there
The range that I would be copying and pasting to would be dynamic because as I add new tables, the place where it would need to be  pasted would change everytime